# Should Magento's blank theme still be used as a theme baseline (Magento version 1.7)?

Tags: magento, themes

A good number of the tutorials I've found on Magento theme development recommend starting off with using blank as a guideline for making your own custom theme.  A lot of these articles are pretty old, as of the current version (1.7), is this still the case?

P.S. - If there are any good/relevant theme development articles out there, aside from Magento's [official design guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide), please feel free to link them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion you should never 'carve out' your own theme from a base theme. You aren't learning theme development in its entirety. You will potentially run into unforeseen consequences. You will likely have excess code and templates by the time you are done.

I wrote a Magento 1.6.1 tutorial on creating a theme that should hold up for 1.7:

http://zaclee.net/magento/make-magento-1-6-theme-from-scratch

If you run into any problems with 1.7 let me know and I'll be glad to take a gander.

Comment: I think somebody mentioned in the comments in your guide, but in 1.7 doing the extension method does not seem to work, and using the module makes the new layout appear in the dropdown list but does not seem to update the actual page (mine still shows the layout from base).

Comment: I noticed that. Making a module should work, however. Will be making a new tutorial in a month, but this is a fairly trivial issue so it shouldn't hold you back.

Comment: `we will be copying the default theme to our own package.` What? Is it a joke?

Comment: I think you got it wrong. I might want to copy `default/default` to your custom package but you should never copy `base/default`.

Comment: @Zyava - Explain why in your comment. Don't just say "don't do this," as it helps no one. And to respond to your comment, copying `base/default` to your own package gives you a namespaced tag of the base theme. If you upgrade Magento later, you won't have any broken code if Magento calls a fallback template and something has changed between versions.

Comment: If you copy `base/default` to your own theme you'll never see new blocks added in the new magento version. Even more, you will never know that they exist. For example, after upgrade to 1.7 with your approach you'll completely miss `Mage_Persistent` module. Additionally, if some block class method was deleted and in your copied template it was called you'll end up with fatal error. That's why I strongly believe (and official design guide even has a note about it) that **you should never copy base/default to your package**.

Comment: @Zyava: I believe you're mistaken; the design guide says not to edit or add themes to the base package. Humorously, not seeing new blocks added in a new version is intended functionality. What if a new version removes functionality your template depends on? That's equally as dangerous as the 'what-if' you listed with block classes being removed. I hope you aren't suggesting store owners do upgrades on a live instance without testing.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with the above answer in the sense that converting an existing theme (ie a commercial theme you've purchased) to fit a design you've been given or done yourself can be more consuming.  You end up doing more deleting than adding, and inevitably end up with a tonne of code that isn't being used (because taking it out might cause problems, the deadline is approaching....sod it, it's only a few Kb, you just leave it in).

However I disagree with the statement that the Magento blank theme will result in excess code and templates.  For a start you only pull in the templates you need and the theme is about as bare bones as it gets.  I always use the blank theme as a basis.  It may well be the case that I am not then learning theme development in it's entirety but the work has to go out, bills have to be paid - and I'm not about to sit and build everything from scratch every time.

Answer (score 0):

To further this discussion, for some time I have really been bugged by the default CSS that Magento ships with. It is a pain to work on, and when you start developing in an environment where multiple people are working on the CSS, you inevitably run into [CSS Kudzu](http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/5-mistakes-of-massive-css).

It's been on my plate for awhile to completely rewrite the default CSS to something more maintainable and trimmed down, but like rabmcnab mentioned, there are deadlines, bills to pay, etc.